# Checking for email intent returns false on actual devices as well

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I have the following piece of code to check for supported intents. The code behaves as expected on the emulator when I check for email support. When I run the same on my actual devices HTC Wildfire and Samsung Galaxy Nexus, the **isEmailSupported** method returns false.

```
public static boolean isEmailSupported(Context context) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "example@example.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum...");
    return isIntentSupported(context, emailIntent);
}

public static boolean isIntentSupported(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> intentActivities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
            intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return intentActivities != null && intentActivities.size() > 0;
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the MIME type that you forgot to include in your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. You must call `setType()` with the MIME type of the content you are putting in `EXTRA_TEXT` (in this case, apparently `text/plain`).